# Перебираем nested hash и необходимо вывести инфу по id

Tags: ruby

Код,который,так скажем, переводит,из плоской модели (Flat) в древовидную модель (Tree).Но мне нужна информация только по `id: '3'`

```
 puts
    puts 'Перебор nested'.green
    a = [
      {id: '1'},
      {id: '2', 'children' => [] },
      {id: '3', 'children' =>
        [
          {id: '3-1'},
          {id: '3-2', 'children' => [] }
        ]
      },
      {id: '4', 'children' => [] }
    ]

    level = 0
    cache = []
    cache[level] = a
    parents = []
    parents[level] = nil
    i = []
    i[level] = 0

    while level >= 0
      node = cache[level][i[level]]
      i[level]+= 1
      if node != nil

        print 'level: '.red; puts level
        # print 'node: '.red; puts node
        # print 'parents: '.red; puts parents

        if !node['children'].nil? && node['children'].length > 0
          level+= 1
          parents[level] = node.clone
          cache[level] = node['children']
          i[level] = 0
        end
      else
        parents[level] = nil
        level-= 1
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше делать через рекурсию (bfs/dfs обход графа):

```
arr = [
  {id: '1'},
  {id: '2', 'children' => [] },
  {id: '3', 'children' =>
    [
      {id: '3-1'},
      {id: '3-2', 'children' => [] }
    ]
  },
  {id: '4', 'children' => [] }
]

def get_by_id_dfs(array, element_id)
  array.each do |el|
    # если находим id то возвращаем текуший хэш
    return el if el[:id] == element_id

    next unless el[:children]

    sub_el = get_by_id_bfs(el[:children], element_id)
    # если нашли id где-то в рекурсии, то возвращаем найденный хэш
    return sub_el if sub_el&.dig(:id) == element_id
  end
  return nil
end

# передаем массив и искомый id
element1 = get_by_id_dfs(arr, '1')
puts element1

element2 = get_by_id_dfs(arr, '3')
puts element2
```

Comment: Отлично,спасибо большое